# iOS textfield cursor position wrong

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield

While toggling iOS textField isSecureTenxtEntry.

[image]

My code is like this

```
textField?.isSecureTextEntry = !textField.isSecureTextEntry
```

Device is iPhone 6.

Comment: Once I start typing cursor moves to correct position.

Comment: are you unable to change secure text entry using this line?

Comment: I'm able to change secure text entry using the code but the cursor is at some distance from the last character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This problem raised due to the different character size of the `secure dot character` and simple character. Dot character are wider in size that's why when you disable secure text entry, character contracts but cursor stays at the same position.

Although this issue should not be in the latest Xcode but I had a same problem in Xcode 6.3.

**Explanation:**

When you click button to toggle the `secureTextEntry`, set the `becomeFirstResponder` again for your textField, it will invoke the keyboard observer and reset the cursor to right position.

```
    textField?.isSecureTextEntry = !textField.isSecureTextEntry

    if textField?.isFirstResponder {
        textField?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, issue fixed by this solution

Answer (score 7):

First discuss why this is happening.

Dot character width is different from normal character, so when you change value of `isSecureTextEntry` property, `UITextField` is not refreshing thats why the extra space appears.

To solve this problem, you can use below code

```
txtPassword.isSecureTextEntry = !txtPassword.isSecureTextEntry
let str = txtPassword.text
txtPassword.text = ""
txtPassword.text = str
```

What I do in above code, after changing value of `isSecureTextEntry` store value in temporary variable and empty the `UITextField` and after that reassign the same `UITextField` by using temporary variable.